# MongoDB Using Transaction for Insert does not persist the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am using mongodb with a replica set (3 replicas). I use **Node.js** with the newest version of the mongodb package. When I use a **transaction to insert a document** and then try to **read the document again** in a new transaction, it will not be found.

I tried using different settings of the transactionOptions but this did not help.
For development I am using the [docker replicaset container](https://hub.docker.com/r/kamalyb/mongo-rs).

Storing the document without a transaction works and it will be found after the `insertOne()`.

```
const {
    MongoClient
} = require('mongodb');
const assert = require('assert');


async function run() {
    const dbName = 'mydb' + new Date().getTime();
    const mongoClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019');
    const mongoDatabase = mongoClient.db(dbName);
    const mongoCollection = await mongoDatabase.createCollection('mycollection');

    // I tried many different transaction options, but this did not help
    const transactionOptions = {
        defaultTransactionOptions: {
            readConcern: {
                w: 3,
                level: 'majority'
            },
            writeConcern: {
                w: 3,
                journal: true
            }
        }
    };

    // insert in one transaction
    let session = mongoClient.startSession(transactionOptions);
    session.startTransaction(transactionOptions);
    await mongoCollection.insertOne({
        bar: 'foo'
    }, { session });
    await session.endSession();

    // find in new transaction
    session = mongoClient.startSession(transactionOptions);
    session.startTransaction(transactionOptions);

    const allDocs = await mongoCollection.find(
        {},
        { session }
    ).toArray();
    console.dir(allDocs);
    assert.strictEqual(allDocs.length, 1); // should have 1 item, but has zero!
    await session.endSession();
}
run();
```

Comment: Well, you will need to commit the transaction: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/commitTransaction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before ending the session you need to call [session.commitTransaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Session.commitTransaction/#session.committransaction--)  to complete the transaction and actually write the data.